# idea ignore maven module name vs directory name difference

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

In project window IDEA shows the hierarchy of maven modules/directories.
If both are commonly named the name is shown in bold letters, otherwise it shows directory name followed by [module name]. 
It is quite unhandy, when the difference is desired.
Does anyone know how to disable this behavior and show only one of both?

(Beside naming equally of course)